# LoginWindow with Caliburn + MEF MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, authentication, caliburn

trying to use a login window with caliburn + mef

I get these two warnings  as well

```
Warning    1    CA2000 : Microsoft.Reliability : In method 'AppBootstrapper.CreateContainer()', call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'container' before all references to it are out of scope.    C:\adl\DotNetProjects\CaliburnTest\CaliburnTest\AppBootstrapper.cs    25    CaliburnTest
Warning    2    CA2000 : Microsoft.Reliability : In method 'AppBootstrapper.CreateContainer()', call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'new AggregateCatalog(Enumerable.Select<Assembly, AssemblyCatalog>(this.SelectAssemblies(), AppBootstrapper.CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1))' before all references to it are out of scope.    C:\adl\DotNetProjects\CaliburnTest\CaliburnTest\AppBootstrapper.cs    25    CaliburnTest
```

Thanks in advance I know that caliburn is going to save me lots of time would love to get this to work!

In this project my IShell is an empty interface.

```
public class AppBootstrapper : Bootstrapper<IShell>
{
    protected override IServiceLocator CreateContainer()
    {
        var container = new CompositionContainer(
            new AggregateCatalog(SelectAssemblies().Select(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)))
            );

        var batch = new CompositionBatch();
        //batch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager());
        return new MEFAdapter(container);
    }
}



[Export(typeof(IShell))]
public class MainViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>, IShell
{
    readonly IWindowManager windowManager;
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MainViewModel(IWindowManager windowManager)
    {
        this.windowManager = windowManager;
        var result = windowManager.ShowDialog(new LoginWindowViewModel());
        if (result != true)
        {
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}

[Export(typeof(LoginWindowViewModel))]
public class LoginWindowViewModel :Screen
{
    public LoginWindowViewModel()
    {
    }
    public  ObservableCollection<User> Users
    {
        get
        {
            if (_users == null)
            {
                _users = new ObservableCollection<User>(){new User("ADMIN","ADMIN","ADMIN")};
            }
            return _users;
        }
    }

    public bool AuthenticateUser(string username, string pass)
    {
        Common.Authenticated.CurrentUser = Users.Where<User>(y => y.Login.Trim() == username.Trim()).FirstOrDefault(y => y.Pass.Trim() == pass.Trim());
        if (Common.Authenticated.CurrentUser != null)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    public bool Authenticated 
    {
        get
        {
            if (Username == null || Username == String.Empty || Password == null || Password == String.Empty)
                return false;
            return AuthenticateUser(Username, Password); 
        }
    }
    public bool CheckAuthNeeded() {return true;}
    private ObservableCollection<User> _users;

    public void Login()
    {    RequestClose(this, new SuccessEventArgs(true));      }
    public string Username {get;set;}
    public string Password {get;set;}

    public event CloseDialogEventHandler RequestClose;
      public delegate void CloseDialogEventHandler(object sender, SuccessEventArgs e);
}
```

**LoginWindowView:**

```
<Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="93*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="185*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,10,0,0">
        <Label Content="Username:"  FontWeight="Bold" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0" Padding="5,5,0,5" />
        <Label Content="Password:"  FontWeight="Bold" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,4,0,0" Padding="5,5,0,5" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,10,10,0">
        <dxe:ComboBoxEdit x:Name="User" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" 
                         Padding="0" Margin="5" DisplayMember="Login" ValueMember="Login" Validate="User_Validate" ValidateOnTextInput="True"
                          AutoComplete="True" ImmediatePopup="True"   IncrementalFiltering="True" ShowEditorButtons="False" />
        <dxe:PasswordBoxEdit x:Name="Pass" Margin="5" Validate="Pass_Validate" ValidateOnTextInput="False"  InvalidValueBehavior="AllowLeaveEditor" />
    </StackPanel> 
    <Button Content="Login" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            x:Name="Login" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" IsDefault="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
</Grid>
```

**LoginWindowView CodeBehind:**

```
public partial class LoginWindowView
{
    public LoginWindowView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void User_Validate(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Value == null)
        {
            e.IsValid = false;
            return;
        }
        var _vm = GetDataContext();
        var u = _vm.Users.FirstOrDefault<User>(x => x.Login.Trim() == ((string)e.Value).Trim().ToUpper());

        if (u == null)
        {
            e.SetError("Invalid Login Name", DevExpress.XtraEditors.DXErrorProvider.ErrorType.Information);
            _vm.Username = string.Empty;
            e.IsValid = false;
        }
        else
            _vm.Username = User.Text;
    }
    public LoginWindowViewModel GetDataContext()
    {
        return (LoginWindowViewModel)DataContext;
    }
    private void Pass_Validate(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value == null)
        {
            e.IsValid = false;
            return;
        }
        var _vm = GetDataContext();
        _vm.Password = ((string)e.Value).ToUpper();
        if (_vm.Authenticated == false)
        {
            e.SetError("Wrong Password.", DevExpress.XtraEditors.DXErrorProvider.ErrorType.Critical);
            e.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
    private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs ee)
    {
        GetDataContext().RequestClose -= (s, e) =>
        {
            this.DialogResult = e.Success;
        };
    }
    private void Window_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OldValue != null)
        {
            ((LoginWindowViewModel)e.OldValue).RequestClose -= (s, ee) =>
            {
                this.DialogResult = ee.Success;
            };
        }
        ((LoginWindowViewModel)e.NewValue).RequestClose += (s, ee) =>
        {
            this.DialogResult = ee.Success;
        };
    }
}

public class User
{
    public string FullName { get; private set; }
    public string Login { get; private set; }
    public string Pass { get; private set; }

    public User(string fullName, string login, string pass) { FullName = fullName; Login = login; Pass = pass; }
    public static User CreateUser(string fullName, string login,string pass)
    {
        return new User(fullName, login,pass);
    }
}




    public static class Authenticated
    {
        public static string AuthString { get; set; }
        public static User CurrentUser { get; set; }
        public static string UserId
        {
            get
            {
                if (CurrentUser != null)
                    return CurrentUser.Login;
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
```

**MainView:**

```
<Window x:Class="CaliburnTest.Views.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainView" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Label>Test</Label>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Could you clean up the question? It would make it easier to attempt an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Rob Eisenberg of caliburn was very helpful and he helped me out with this issue.

The problem was that when I switched to caliburn the LoginView was the first window to be opened and it was closed before the MainView window was opened.

windows treats the first window opened as the mainwindow.  and when the mainwindow is closed windows checks if other windows are open if not it closes the application.

He provided a possible solution of making the loginviewmodel the shell and closing it  after opening the mainviewmodel.